# ModuleNotFoundError (relative to healpy)

Tags: python

After installing healpy, running the  gives me the message ModuleNotFoundError. I know healpy is not supported by Windows, but it was told me that, on Googlecolab, it should work instead.

Comment: show the python code please. we need to see something!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).